# How to use variables from one function in other functions

Tags: python-3.x

This is small adding program in python, but i want to use variables `(num1,num2)` in `insert()` function to another `sum()` function  how can solve this.

```
def insert():
    num1 = 2
    num2 = 4
def sum():
    add = num1 + num2
    print(add)
def main():
    sum()
 main()
```

Comment: Please correct your indentation, first. And explain that what's your problem with the code?

Comment: I am unable to call num1 and num2 into sum() and when i run this  error message num1 is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The variables `num1` and `num2` has been defined as local variables inside the `insert()` function so you can not use them inside another function which use it's own namespace.

For getting ride of this problem you can return that variables in `insert` and then pass the returned variables to `sum` function as arguments.

```
def insert():
    num1 = 2
    num2 = 4
    return num1,num2
a,b=insert()
def sum(num1,num2):
    add = num1 + num2
    print(add)
def main():
    a,b=insert()
    sum(a,b)
main()
```

Note that this is an example and if you want to just create some variables  you can create them in top level of your module.

Also you can use `global` expression to define a variable as global inside the function but this is not a safe and pythonic as returning the values and passing them as argument.

```
def insert():
    global num1
    global num2
    num1 = 2
    num2 = 4

def sum():
    add = num1 + num2
    print(add)
def main():
    sum()
main()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Know how can i use the variables into sum() is there any methods please explain by using my scenario.